# After converting MVC 4 project to MVC 5 I am getting "this website has redirect loop"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After converting MVC 4 project to MVC 5 I am getting an error "this website has redirect loop". In my web.config file I have the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Register" timeout="2880" />      
</authentication>
```

When I try to click on any menu item, it tries to redirect to /Account/Register page. This was working fine before the conversion. How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to clear cookies?

Comment: To see what is going on exactly, it might be helpful to install Fiddler2 on your PC. This application logs your HTTP(S) traffic and is very good for debugging purpose. See: http://fiddler2.com